# How to keep the work space of executing method in matlab?

Tags: matlab, function

I want to use script file as function because somehow, I need to define methods in script file and it is not possible in script file. However, when I defines script as function and execute it then I lose work space and I can not do  further analysis of variables. I do not want to set breakpoints in code. Is there a way to keep work space alive for further analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the function:

```
save filename;
evalin('caller','load filename');
```

Comment: Can you explain, what is happening.

Comment: well, this saves all the variables in the current ws to a file called filename.mat. evalin('caller','load filename'); then loads the content of the .mat-file into the callers ws

Comment: It creates a file named filename.mat with the content of all variables.

Answer (score 1):

I just got an evil solution:

```
%get all the var-names of the fcn-workspace
myVars=who('*')
for var=myVars'
    assignin('base',var{:},eval(var{:}))
end
```

..this will work, but it is eval :)

Comment: I am getting only name of variables but no values.